# How can I exclude data for certain tables but keep structure with mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, database-backups

I'm doing a regular dump of a database that uses the database for logging. I need to create a `mysqldump` command that dumps everything from the database but excludes the row information for the log tables.

I see [the `no-data` parameter](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data), but that doesn't seem to support selecting only certain tables.

Comment: @ajreal Linux. Does that matter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Run 2 commands. One where you list all tables that you want a full dump of, one where you dump only the table definition

```
#structure only
mysqldump -d -q mydb table1 table2 table3

#all data too
mysqldump -q mydb table4 table5 table6
```

Answer (score 9):

you can combine with shell script to help better

```
#/bin/bash

# dump all except for table log
tables=$(mysql -N <<< "show tables from your_db" | grep -Ev "^log$" | xargs); 
mysqldump your_db $tables > backup.sql

# dump structure for table log
mysqldump -d your_db log >> backup.sql
```